# PHP/CSS find word in string, change its color

Tags: php, css

PHP/CSS find word in string, change its color for display. Having a problem, can't find its solution, any suggestions?  thanks.

```
      <pre>

      <?php 
      $str="Try to realize the truth... there is no spoon."; // spoon can be anywhere in string
      $array = explode(" ", $str);
for($i=0;$i < count($array);$i++)
     {
       if ($array[$i] == "spoon") {
             ?><span style="color:red;"><?php echo echo $array[$i]." "; ?></span>
             <?php
           } else {
              echo $array[$i]." ";
           }   
     } ?>

      </pre
```

Comment: Why not use a `preg_replace`?

Comment: Why not just `str_replace('spoon', '<span style="color:red;">spoon</span>', $str)`? Or as @Matt correctly suggests `preg_replace()` can do essentially the same thing with a little more flexibility.

Comment: Keep it simple.  Try it again using `str_replace()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: You are you exploding your string on spaces `" "`, but if you notice, there is a period after `spoon` in your sentence. So, in your array you end up with `spoon.` and not `spoon` as you are expecting.

Comment: @DaveRandom I would use `preg_replace` just in case there exist more than one instance of the search term.

Comment: I'm only a month here and have seen this question 3 times already.

Comment: @DainisAbols Get used to it. If people were capable of using Google correctly there would be like 1/10 of the questions posted here.

Comment: The "spoon" word could be in a different position within string $str="there is no spoon. Try to realize the truth";

Comment: While I agree with most and believe that he should be using an alternative like str_replace or preg_replace I think something must be said about trying to solve this from "scratch".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would personally use:

```
function highlight($text='', $word='')
{
  if(strlen($text) > 0 && strlen($word) > 0)
  {
    return (str_ireplace($word, "<span class='hilight'>{$word}</span>", $text));
  }
   return ($text);
}

$str="Try to realize the truth... there is no spoon."; // spoon can be anywhere in string
$str= highlight($str, 'spoon');
```

**Note:** str_ireplace is the Case-insensitive version str_replace.

Also... obviously you will need to define the css for 'hilight' somewhere!

Comment: No problem. I actually use it also in a Smarty modifier if you use smarty at all for presentation I can share that too.

Comment: Have not used the Smarty engine but yes please share. I am venturing into the twitter parsing world currently this week ~ hence the red spoon challenge.  every week is different!

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `preg_replace()`.

```
preg_replace('/\b(spoon)\b/i', '<span style="color:red;">$1</span>', $str);
```

**Notes from DaveRandom:**

`\b` is a word boundary assertion to ensure you don't match teaspoon or spoonman, and `()` is a capture group to use in the replace so the casing stays the same.

`i` at the end ensures case-insensitivity, and `$1` will place the matched word back in your replace string.

Comment: I'm thinking `/\b(spoon)\b/i` and `<span style="color:red;">$1</span>`, otherwise you may as well just `str_replace()`

Comment: @DaveRandom legitimate question - what's the purpose of `\b(...)\b`?

Comment: @DaveRandom, never mind. I looked it up myself. "What have you tried" indeed!

Comment: A word boundary assertion (`\b`) to ensure you don't match `teaspoon` or `spoonman`, and a capture group (`(...)`) to use in the replace so the casing stays the same.

Comment: The `/i` and the `$1` in the replace are important too... ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom What about the `i` at the end there?

Comment: That makes in case-insensitive, and that's what the capture group was for so you can drop the matched string into the middle of the span instead of accidentally lowercasing `SPOON`

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks! I will include your explanations in the answer (with credit to you, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because when you explode on the " "(space), you expect to receive an array with the word "spoon", but in reality its the word "spoon." (note the period) that gets added to the array and why your conditional statement `if ($array[$i] == "spoon")` never triggers.

**Note:**
While I agree with most and believe that he should be using an alternative like str_replace or preg_replace I think something must be said about trying to solve this from "scratch".

Answer (score 1):

You can't find "spoon" because you explode a space, so you just will get "spoon."

You can do this in one line:

```
str_replace("spoon", "<span style=\"color:red;\">spoon</span>", $str);
```

Hope this helps.