# Finding words and changing the color

Tags: php, html, css

I want to change the color of my text found in the ECHO function using CSS and conditions.

For Example:

*I call text using the ECHO function:*

```
echo ": The net value of the entire order"
echo ": The gross value of the entire order"
echo ": The gross value of the entire order"
echo ": The net value of the entire order"
```

And using the condition "if" find the word "net" or "gross" and change the color to red or blue ..

How to do it ? I was looking for forums but the posts were only for assigned values ​​in variables, and I want to change the color from the ECHO function, it may seem senseless but if there are thousands of such words?

I am asking you for help,
I am new in this language.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. We expect you to have done some research and made some attempts to solve your problem on your own, and then provide the attempted result(s) with a specific problem at hand, which is what your question revolves around. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847091/php-css-find-word-in-string-change-its-color I think it's your need.

Comment: Probably the solution is better but I still do not use it. I need functions or conditions that search for a word in ECHO.

Comment: But why do you have to do it in echo? Tell us a bit more

Comment: `echo` will emit the strings directly to output buffer which may be connected to actual output. As a result, it might be too late to try doing any modifications to the string after the `echo` has been executed. If you really need to do that (e.g. compatibility with some 3rd party code), see `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` for a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

```
$str = ": The net value of the entire order"

$str = str_replace('net', '<span style="color:red">net</span>', $str);
$str = str_replace('gross', '<span style="color:blue">gross</span>', $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: but I wrote that I do not want to define anything, it has to be a condition or a function that searches for these words and changes color !!

Comment: What you're asking doesn't really make sense. So you want CSS to search and replace occurrences of a string in PHP's HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "The gross value of the entire order";
$wordOptions = [
    "net" => "#aaaaaa",
    "gross" => "#bbbbbb"
];

foreach($wordOptions as $word => $color){
    str_replace($word, "<span style=\"color: {$color};\">{$word}</span>", $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="The net value of the entire order";

preg_replace('/\b(net)\b/i', '<span style="color:red;">net</span>', $str);
```